# How to Solve an equation with mod for a variable?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations

I have following equation to be solved, but I am having some trouble in making an understanding and doing so.

`(d * e) % v = 1`

**e** and **v** are known. How to solve this to get value of **d** ?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is equivalent to solving $$de \equiv 1 \pmod v$$ Search for "modular inverse" to learn how to divide through by $e$. Note that there is no solution if $\gcd(e,v) \neq 1$. Keywords to find the computational method involved are "extended gcd" and "extended euclidean algorithm".

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to solve this modular equation. First is to start adding $v$'s to $1$ until $1 + nv$ for some arbitrary number $n$ is a multiple of $d$. so we have:

$$de \equiv 1 \equiv 1 + nv \pmod v$$

So after division we have:

$$e \equiv \frac{1 + nv}{d} \pmod v$$

If the modular equation have solution, in worst case you would have to add $v$'s in $d$ times.

Also you could solve it by Linear Diphantene Equation using Euclidean Algorithm. We have:

$$de \equiv 1 \pmod v \iff de - 1 = vk$$

So you need to solve the equation and find integer solution $de - vk = 1$, where variables are $e$ and $k$. Note that if $gcd(d,v) \neq 1$ this equation doesn't have solution, this follows from Bezout's Lemma.

And other method is using Gauss method. Your goul would be to bring the fraction: $\frac{1}{d}$ to an integer using multiplication, division and modular arithmetics. But note that you mustn't divide or multiply by factors of $v$, otherwise the calculation will go wrong.